# What phrase to use in this situation?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

I am working on a statistic problem. I define "A" as the number of all the products in the warehouse, but some of the products are not qualified and I need another parameter to describe the number of the qualified products, for example, "B". Then, what should I say about B? Could I say that B is the number of all the products *except for* the unqualified ones? Is "except for" a proper expression? May I have other words or phrases that fit the situation better? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'A' as all products in the warehouse and 'B' as all qualified products in the warehouse.

If instead we use an exclusion method, such as 'B' as all products in the warehouse excluding all unqualified products, it suggests that 'B' contains products that are qualified plus products that have not yet been processed to a qualified or unqualified state.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you mean that, if I use an exclusion method, B could include some products that are neither qualified or unqualified?

Comment: With or without the exclusion method, the potential existence of products that are neither qualified nor qualified must be considered, and therefore we should decide which group would include them, if they exist.
The exclusion method merely emphasizes that such a group could exist, otherwise why do we not use the simpler 'B' as all qualified products form.

Comment: I think I take your point. Thanks again for your quick response.